# Update column value for a specified time range in Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

A Hive table "Employee" contains a column "timerange", and the data is

```
timerange
1:10
1:13
1:17
1:21
1:26
```

If the last digit range is between (0 & 4), the data must be updated as 0. If the last digit range is between (5 & 9) must be updated as 5.

Expected output is

```
timerange
1:10
1:10
1:15
1:20
1:25
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's data type of timerange??

Comment: String is the datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through built-in string manipulation:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(timerange, LENGTH(timerange)) < "5"
            THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(timerange, 1, LENGTH(timerange) - 1), "0")
            ELSE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(timerange, 1, LENGTH(timerange) - 1), "5")
       END AS timerange
FROM Employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic UDF ([GenericUDF](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDF.html)).

Here is a sample UDF:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentLengthException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.IntObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.StringObjectInspector;

public class TimeRangeConverter GenericUDF {

    @Override
    public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments) throws UDFArgumentException {
        if (arguments.length != 1) {
            throw new UDFArgumentLengthException("The function time_range_converter(time_rage) requires 1 argument.");
        }

        ObjectInspector timeRangeVal = arguments[0];

        if (!(timeRangeVal instanceof StringObjectInspector)) {
            throw new UDFArgumentException("First argument must be of type String (time_range as String)");
        }
        return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector;
    }

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
        String timeRangeVal = (String) ObjectInspectorUtils.copyToStandardJavaObject(arguments[0].get(),
                PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector);

        char[] characters = timeRangeVal.toCharArray();

        if (characters[characters.length - 1] > '5') {
            characters[characters.length - 1] = '5';
        } else {
            characters[characters.length - 1] = '0';
        }

        return String.valueOf(characters);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString(String[] arguments) {
        assert (arguments.length == 1);
        return "time_range_converter(" + arguments[0] + ")";
    }
}
```

Call the Hive update statement like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION time_range_converterAS 'TimeRangeConverter';

UPDATE 
    Employee 
SET 
    timerange = time_range_converter(timerange);
```